# a data monitoring infrastructure to ensure integrity of data

Tags: testing, monitoring, integrity

We work on some important, financial data(= it is transactional data in the databases world ) and do a lot of transformations and processing on them and save the result to different sorts of filesystems, databases, and so on.

we want to do different kinds of tests on our output data to ensure the integrity of data preserved based on input data. how can we approach this issue in big data? what is your advice? is there any framework to use?

thank you in advance